# The classical projection theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, projection

I am going over a proof of the classical projection theorem which states the following:
Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $M$ a closed subspace of $H$. Corresponding to any vector $x \in H$, there is a unique vector $m_0 \in M$ such that $||x-m_0|| \le ||x-m||$ for all $m \in M$. I know that the minimizing vector $m_0$ is such that $x-m_0$ is orthogonal to M. The solution boils down to showing that there is an $m_0$ such that $\delta=\text{inf}_{m \in M}||x-m||=||x-m_0||$. So far so good. However, the author goes into a great length showing that a sequence $\{m_i\}$ so that $||x-m_i|| \rightarrow \delta$ is a Cauchy sequence and using the fact that $M$ is a complete space.

What I don't understand is the following: isn't the fact that $M$ is closed implies that the set $M^1=\{x-m|m \in M\}$ is also closed? Therefore, there is an $m_0 \in M$ such that $\delta=||x-m_0||$. Obviously I am missing something in the reasoning here..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you spell out your argument in more detail? How does the fact that $M^1$ is closed imply that there exists $m_0 \in M$ such that $\delta = \| x - m_0\|$?

Comment: Sure, sorry about that. Since $M^1$ is closed, it contains its limit points so that $\delta \in M^1$.

Comment: Your argument requires you to be able to extract a convergent sequence of points in $M$ such that $\|x - m_n\| \to \delta$. This is where the problem lies. In general, continuous functions on compact sets attain their minima but continuous functions on closed sets don't have to. In infinite dimensional spaces, norm compact sets are hard to come by.

Comment: The function $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, and $\mathbb{R}$ is closed. The image of $\mathbb{R}$ under $f$ is $(0,1]$, which is not closed in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your argument is that in order to conclude from the fact that $M^1$ contains its limit points that there is an $m_0 \in M$ such that $\delta = \|x - m_0\|$ you already need to know that there is a limit point of $M$ such that $\delta = \|x - m_0\|$. This does not come for free from the definition of $\delta$. The approximation property of the $\inf$ tells you that there is a sequence $m_n \in M$ such that $\|x - m_n\| \to \delta$ but this does not tell you that $m_n$ has a convergent subsequence a priori and so you don't get the desired limit point.

The authors argument that $(m_n)_{n \geq 1}$ must be Cauchy is exactly a proof that the desired limit point must exist since Cauchy sequences must converge and the limit of $(m_n)$ is then the desired limit point.

Comment: Hi Rhys! Thanks for commenting. Isn't $\delta$ a limit point of $M^1$?

Comment: It's not even in the same space. $M_1$ is a subset of $H$ whilst $\delta$ is a real number.

Comment: ok i see what i did there.. I mixed up the spaces